# Generate Radio Field for each element in a questionnaire

Tags: flask, wtforms

So I'm using wtforms to generate radio fields but I need them to be dynamic like if there are 12 questions each question would get a set of radio fields. I  tried FormField which gave me what i wanted but the names are same for all the questions is there a better way to do this?

the output should be like this:

```
Question
Radiofield1 radioField1

Question
Radiofield2 radioField2
```

**Edit**:
I moved on to complete HTML fields but it would be really helpful.
I don't remember much as to what I did but this was close to it I could render the fields but the id wouldn't change I tried passing the tuples to

**options** but it rendered dynamic radio fields for each question rather than 1 set for each question

> Forms.py

```
class QuestionRadio(FlaskForm):
    rad=RadioField("rad",choices=[(1,'Yes'),(2,'No')],id="opt")

class QuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    options=FieldList(FormField(QuestionRadio),min_entries=1)
```

> Views.py

```
    #This is the question list  
    question=[(ques.id,ques.question) for ques in Questions.query.all()]
    form=QuestionForm()
    #I don't remember what I did after this
```

> template.html

```
{% for key,val in question %}

<h4>key. val</h4>

 {{form.options}}


{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [wforms documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/specific_problems/#dynamic-form-composition) suggests creating a dummy class and dynamically adding fields in your view.

This is the example from the documentation:

```
def my_view():
    class F(MyBaseForm):
        pass

    F.username = StringField('username')
    for name in iterate_some_model_dynamically():
        setattr(F, name, StringField(name.title()))

    form = F(request.POST, ...)
    # do view stuff
```

In your case the code might look something like this (untested):

```
def my_view():
    class QuestionForm(Form):
        pass

    for q in Questions.query.all():
        field = RadioField(q.question,choices=[(1,'Yes'),(2,'No')],id=q.id)
        setattr(QuestionForm, q.id, field)

    form = QuestionForm(request.POST, ...)
    # do view stuff
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to render this in the template, I tried this too but could't figure how to display it