# Is there a way to make variable-length WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Im trying to make a Website where users can create quizzes that are then answerable with a WTForm.

The problem is that the number of questions is variable and when I try to make the forms I can't just make a list of the question fields like this:

```
questions = ["How are you?", "Whats your favourite food?"]
answers = [["Good", "Bad"], ["Pizza", "Chips", "Pasta"]]

class MyForm(Form):
    quiz = []
    for question, answer in zip(questions, answers):
        quiz.append(SelectField(question, choices=answer)
    name = StringField("Whats your name?")
```

This is because the fields in the list aren't "inititalized" (?) when initialing the form using

```
MyForm()
```

like the StringField would (they are still UnboundField?). I found out that there is a FieldList in WTForms but apparently it is only for having the same field multiple times.
Is there a way to initialise the fields in the __init__ function or to do what i'm trying to using FieldList?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952933/generate-radio-field-for-each-element-in-a-questionnaire is very similar

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks, i think it adresses the same problem

Comment: @snakecharmerb but how would i render this template? Can i access the attributes of a class as a dict somehow?

Comment: Loop over the fields, and for the FieldList, loop over the contained fields, something like `{% for field in form %}{% if field.name = 'quiz' %}{% for subfield in subfield %}....` (assuming you're using jinja2)